# How to keep center item of listview with one color always while scrolls in android

Tags: android

i have a listview. the center item of list should be in diff color.when scrolls.,the items comes at that particular position should change that color & contin. back to original colr after cross that position. do u know how it is?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can probably use an Android wheel picker

http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

It highlights the center item and can be modified however you want it to look when the item you want comes to the center.

Comment: I think the developer of the widget has explained how to use the code here :http://android-devblog.blogspot.in/